# linq make call from each iternation

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the folloiwng linq query

```
var results = mainList.Select(item => new {
                               spResult: sp_getsys(item.PSID, 
                                                   item.Nominprsn),
                                            PSID: item.PSID,
                                            Nominprsn: item.Nominprsn
                                 });
```

Mainlist is has 2 rows. One for PSID and the other for Nominprsn
For each iteration, I need to call a stored procedure called sp_getsys.
The result of spResult is a list with 8 rows. I need to get the 2nd row and further more get the field called PSDate.
How can I modify  spResult: sp_getsys(item.PSID, item.Nominprsn) above to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would do the job, but it seems like it may just be a better idea to break this out into a foreach loop to gain some clarity.

```
var results = from item in mainList
              select new
              {
                  spResult = sp_getsys(item.PSID, item.Nominprsn).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().PSDate,
                  PSID = item.PSID,
                  Nominprsn = item.Nominprsn
              };
```